# No bootable deive found for Fedora after moving partitions

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, fedora, fdisk

*As a word of caution: I am inexperienced and moved some partitions around when attempting to dual boot windows from Fedora, I didn't take note of what I was doing and so only have  my current situation to work from and nothing to work back towards. I know I should have backed up but here we are.*

When I try to boot into my Fedora filesystem on my DELL Inspiron 7400 from the boot menu, I receive a `No bootable devices found error`.

I am currently using Fedora from a live USB.

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: KBG40ZNS512G NVMe KIOXIA 512GB          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3A1641E9-8A61-4571-84A5-5A4B01FE1FEF

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    1230847   1228800   600M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1230848    3327999   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3   3328000  481832959 478504960 228.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p4 481832960 1000214527 518381568 247.2G Microsoft basic data
GPT PMBR size mismatch (3979243 != 240328703) will be corrected by write.
The backup GPT table is not on the end of the device.
```

Output of `lsblk -f` for the relevant drive:

```
NAME        FSTYPE   FSVER            LABEL                 UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1                                                                                                         
├─nvme0n1p1 exfat    1.0                                    E3FF-EA47                                           
├─nvme0n1p2 ext4     1.0                                    98871ee5-1638-4cce-ad50-8668e8ddca31                
├─nvme0n1p3 btrfs                     fedora_localhost-live 2f90f992-e665-42ac-b8d0-0452f56c3413                
└─nvme0n1p4 exfat    1.0                                    67ED-F63F
```

`nvme0n1p3` is my Fedora file system which I am attempting to recover.

`nvme0n1p4` is a partition I created prior which was supposed to store Windows 10.

To show the contents of `/etc/fstab` I mounted `nvme0n1p3` and other relevant virtual filesystems with

```
$ mount -t btrfs -o subvol=root,compress=zstd:1 UUID=2f90f992-e665-42ac-b8d0-0452f56c3413 /mnt
$ for dir in sys proc run dev ; do mount --bind /$dir /mnt/$dir ; done
```

and entered a chroot environment for the installed OS.

```
$ chroot /mnt
```

Current mounted partitions are

```
$ mount
/dev/nvme0n1p3 on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,compress=zstd:1,ssd,space_cache=v2,subvolid=257,subvol=/root)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,size=3218672k,nr_inodes=819200,mode=755,inode64)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=4096k,nr_inodes=1048576,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel)
/dev/nvme0n1p3 on /home type btrfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,compress=zstd:1,ssd,space_cache=v2,subvolid=256,subvol=/home)
```

`/boot/efi` is not mounted. When I attempt to mount it I get

```
$ mount /boot/efi
mount: /boot/efi: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

From the chroot environment, the contents of `/etc/fstab` is:

```
UUID=2f90f992-e665-42ac-b8d0-0452f56c3413 /                       btrfs   subvol=root,compress=zstd:1 0 0
UUID=98871ee5-1638-4cce-ad50-8668e8ddca31 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=E3FF-EA47 /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2
UUID=2f90f992-e665-42ac-b8d0-0452f56c3413 /home                   btrfs   subvol=home,compress=zstd:1 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-USB_SanDisk_3.2Gen1_01014b4983299e0e5a6c1f9f3d81280741420402818084341748ec522098bd28ad3d0000000000000000000034beffdcff0c520091558107b7ad0543-0:0 /mnt/usb-USB_SanDisk_3.2Gen1_01014b4983299e0e5a6c1f9f3d81280741420402818084341748ec522098bd28ad3d0000000000000000000034beffdcff0c520091558107b7ad0543-0:0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

I have been trying to fix this issue for a while and have attempted the following:

- `nvme0n1p1` (labelled as the EFI partition) was formatted at `nfts` when the issue initially occured, following online advice I reformatted this to `exfat` using Gparted
- Then I then manually mounted `nvme0n1p1` at `/boot/efi`.
- Finally I changed the UUID in `etc/fstab` to match this. This is the current UUID shown for `nvme0n1p1`.

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/737081/108618).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you have bashed your Windows UEFI partition ($ mount /boot/efi).

Best thing to do at this point is to reinstall Windows properly so it makes the required Windows partitions.

Then put Fedora into a Virtual Machine so that you do not bash Windows trying to learn another OS.  I do this and it works really well.

Comment: Any advice for restoring data from the installed Fedora partition?

Comment: You would need to boot from a bootable USB Key and see if you can recover data from the working partition if you can get to it.